# How to add ICA connections in Citrix Connection Center?

Tags: citrix

I installed Citrix Desktop Receiver on my home computer, so I can access some resources at work.

When I open the Citrix Connection Center there isn't a way for me to add new connections.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Mac OS X?

Comment: Windows XP Pro SP2

Comment: Also, do you know which version is on the server at work? Is is XenApp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I am using an older Citrix Client.

If you have something called the Citrix "Program Neighborhood", you can open that and click the icon that says "Add ICA Connection" and fill out the appropriate details to connect to the server(s) at work.

I hope this helps.

Update: In response to you comment below, I've uploaded the [v10.0 Citrix client](http://cli.gs/citrixV10) that I am using.

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Kevin,

I've googled around and seen reference to that program but I haven't seen anything on the Citrix site where I can download it.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for adding that file.  I actually ended up getting the same file from my IT guy.   It turns out what I had originally downloaded (Desktop Receiver) was not what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully someone will Google this question in the future and get the file they need from my link.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, do a right click and "Add New Connection".

**EDIT:**

I couldn't find the ICA client at the citrix download site anymore.
It seems that XenDesktop is the replacement for the normal ICA Client.
I hate it when companies rename their products with no reference to the old ones, arrrgh.

Comment: Sadly, no luck with that one

Comment: I have added a link to Citrix client v 10 below. The file is hosted on my personal website.